# What are the distinct functions a body orifice could have?

Tags: biology, creature-design, anatomy

Different types of animal have different sorts of orifice with different functions. One commonality between them is that multiple different functions (often the same functions across multiple animals) are condensed into one orifice

My question is to ask which of these oft-combined functions are distinct features, which could be split across multiple orifices in certain animals. I hope to curate a list of distinct functions in the answers

Comment: What is the worldbuilding problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @L.Dutch I aim to know which functions would realistically always appear together and which could be separated out to different orifices

Comment: Asking for us to enumerate all the potential uses for a thing isn't a suitable question for this site. Questions need to be specific not open ended.

Comment: @sphennings Finite lists are allowed, and this is clearly a finite list

Comment: @IchthysKing the list of potential uses is too broad to be suitable for this site. We're a worldbuilding site so the only limits are those you choose to impose on yourself and your creativity.

Comment: @sphennings In what way is it too broad?

Comment: @IchthysKing “finite” maybe, but 52! is also “finite”

Comment: @Topcode Are there 52! different distinct purposes that an orifice can have?

Comment: @IchthysKing probably could be, either way my point is that any inconveniently large lists aren’t allowed.

Comment: @Topcode How is this list so inconveniently large? Can you show that?

Comment: @IchthysKing i can’t show that without making a very large list of all possible functions, which is inconvenient

Comment: Spiracle, sweat gland, sebaceous gland, hair follicle, malpignian tubules, wax glands, preen glands, nasonov gland, scent gland, tear duct, cloaca, lactation duct (collection of = nipple), urethra, vagina, mucus gland................ The list of orifices alone is far too large, it's very definitely far too long to fit in our format here. Fails the book test.

Comment: @AngryMuppet Small openings found over the skin are generally not considered orifices, and the rest don't really make up such a large number

Comment: This looks a lot more like a biology question rather than a worldbuilding one. But I'll assume you aren't, so let's take it worldbuildingly : any answer is equally valid, because you tell nothing about *your* world and the creatures there. It probably plays a part on why it's thought to be too broad, too :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of distinct orifices, with a note to show an example of an organ with such a distinction

- Eating (mouth)
- Drinking (springtail collophore)
- Coughing (hagfish gills)
- Olfaction (fish nostrils)
- Breathing (slug pneumostome)
- Breathing Outlet (fish gills)
- Speech (herring anus or human mouth)
- Hearing (mammal ear)
- Sperm (penis)
- Sperm Acceptance (kangaroo side vagina)
- Birth (kangaroo middle vagina)
- Urination (urethra)
- Defecation (anus)